# Python Tkinter: How do I change two string variables with one button with a delay in between?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python/tkinter and I was wondering how I could press one button and make two variables change text but with a 1 second delay in between. For example, if I click a button, text1 will change to "changed" and then one second later, have text2 change to "changed". Thank you!

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

x = tk.Tk()
root = tk.Frame(x)
root.grid()

def change(str1,str2):
    str1.set("Changed")
    sleep(1)
    str2.set("Changed")

str1 = tk.StringVar()
str2 = tk.StringVar()

str1.set("One")
str2.set("Two")

text1 = tk.Label(root,textvariable=str1)
text2 = tk.Label(root,textvariable=str2)
text1.grid(row=1)
text2.grid(row=1,column=1)

button1 = tk.Button(root,text="Click",command=lambda:change(str1,str2))
button1.grid()

x.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `time.sleep` will block your main thread. You can use the `after` method which you can read it up [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).

```
import tkinter as tk

x = tk.Tk()
root = tk.Frame(x)
root.grid()

def change(str1,str2):
    str1.set("Changed")
    root.after(1000,lambda: str2.set("Changed"))

str1 = tk.StringVar()
str2 = tk.StringVar()

str1.set("One")
str2.set("Two")

text1 = tk.Label(root,textvariable=str1)
text2 = tk.Label(root,textvariable=str2)
text1.grid(row=1)
text2.grid(row=1,column=1)

button1 = tk.Button(root,text="Click",command=lambda:change(str1,str2))
button1.grid()

x.mainloop()
```